# ASP.NET Login/Membership - How to logout?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-membership, umbraco, login-control

I am using the `<asp:LoginStatus>` control (along with `<asp:Login>`)

I login successfully as **A**.
Then I logout.
If I then login as **B**, the current user is still **A**.
(Both `<asp:LoginName>` and `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` are showing **A**)

I have to clear the cookies to completely logout.

Why doesn't the .NET login control log me out properly? Anyone has any idea?

**EDIT**: I apologize everyone! This is an **Umbraco bug**. I forgot I was using UmbracoMembershipProvider

Comment: You said : 'If I then login as B, the current user is still A.', Could you please tell us how you find it out that user still is a ?

Comment: By any chance is the page\control cached?

Comment: How are you logging out exactly? on logout you should call Session.Abandon then redirect to login page and check in debugger that context.current.user.isauthenticated is false at this point.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

On logout to completely clear out the logged in user I would use:

```
Session.Clear()
Session.Abandon()
FormsAuthentication.SignOut()
FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage()
```

Comment: I added onloggedout on my LoginStatus as follows<br>

    `<asp:LoginStatus ... onloggedout="LoginStatus1_LoggedOut" />`

and this<br>

  `protected void LoginStatus1_LoggedOut(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    Session.Clear();
    Session.Abandon();
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();

    string user = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name; // But this still shows A!

    FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
  }`

Comment: Sorry I can't put a line break there. In short, I have done what you suggested but it doesn't clear `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`

Comment: Sorry, forget it, this is an Umbraco bug!

Answer (score 2):

I'll just accept Ira's answer because my question was wrong.

This is the solution to the Umbraco bug:

Add an onloggedout to the LoginStatus

```
<asp:LoginStatus ... onloggedout="UmbracoLogout" />
```

that manually clears the cache

```
  protected void UmbracoLogout(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    Member.RemoveMemberFromCache(Member.CurrentMemberId());
    Member.ClearMemberFromClient(Member.CurrentMemberId());
  }
```

(from http://our.umbraco.org/projects/website-utilities/nforum/bugs/18405-Cache-problem)