# How to login with login control and when logged in go to myPage.aspx not Default.aspx in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to login with login control and when logged in go to myPage.aspx not Default.aspx in asp.net?

I want to when logged in go to myPage and give me Information of user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Login Control has a property **DestinationPageUrl**.  Set your desired page to DestinationPageUrl.

```
<asp:Login DestinationPageUrl="~/myPage.aspx" ID="LoginUser" runat="server" EnableViewState="false"  RenderOuterTable="false">
        ---------------------
        ---------------------
        ---------------------
</asp:Login>
```

Also if you want to show userName on your page, you can use HeadLoginView Control Like.

```
 <asp:LoginView ID="HeadLoginView" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">                   
    <LoggedInTemplate>
        Welcome <span class="bold"><asp:LoginName ID="HeadLoginName" runat="server" /></span>!                      
    </LoggedInTemplate>
</asp:LoginView>
```

OR
Use following line of code to get current login user.

```
System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser().ToString();
```

For SignOut use `FormsAuthentication`

```
    protected void LogOut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session.Clear();
        Session.Abandon();
        System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
//if you want to redirect to your desired page just use following line instead of RedirectToLoginPage
//Response.Redirect("myPage.aspx");
    }
```

Also see link below, may you get more help.

[ASP.NET Login/Membership - How to logout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7831945/asp-net-login-membership-how-to-logout)

Comment: how to sign out by programming and go to myPage?

Comment: I edit my answer, and hope you will find the answers.

Comment: I do not want use login status control. I want build logout  myself by programing ang click in a button